# How to convert a vector of strings to a dataframe or matrix

Tags: r

I have a vector of n-length strings of numerals that looks like this (in this case, n=3):

```
[1] "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111"
[13] "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111"
[25] "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "111" "1 1" "111" "  1" "111" "112"
[37] "121" "111" "111" "111" "11 " "111" "   " "111" "111" "221" "111" "111"
[49] "   " "111" "111"
```

I want to convert it into a matrix (or dataframe) that looks like this:

```
V1   V2   V3
1    1    1
1    1    1
1    1    1
...
1   NA    1
1    1    1
NA   NA   1
```

etc.

I know I can do it in a doubly-nested loop with substring() and as.numeric(), but there must be a more R-like way to accomplish this. Can anyone offer a clue?

TIA.

Comment: I think a bit more clarification would be helpful.  To me it's not clear how you jump from a to b.  Alsoplease provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `strsplit`.  For example (assuming your vector is an object named `x`):

```
y <- strsplit(x,"")
z <- lapply(y, as.numeric)
a <- do.call(rbind, z)
```

This will be faster than the above solution, but is less intuitive.  `sapply` simplifies to an array, but you have to transpose it because the dimensions are opposite of what you want.

```
a <- t(sapply(y, as.numeric))
```

Here's a comparison of the timings of the different methods proposed in the answers (so far):

```
x <- sample(c("111","1 1","  1","112","121","11 ","   ","221"), 1e5, TRUE)
f1 <- function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(x,""), as.numeric))
f2 <- function(x) t(sapply(strsplit(x,""), as.numeric))
f3 <- function(x) read.fwf(file=textConnection(x), widths=c(1,1,1))
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), replications=10, order="relative",
  columns=c("test","replications","elapsed","relative"))
#    test replications elapsed  relative
# 2 f2(x)           10   5.072  1.000000
# 1 f1(x)           10   6.343  1.250591
# 3 f3(x)           10 119.892 23.638013
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution using `read.fwf()`.

```
x <- c("111", "   ", "221", "  1")

## "fwf" stands for "*f*ixed *w*idth *f*ormatted"
read.fwf(file = textConnection(x), widths = c(1,1,1))
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  1  1
# 2 NA NA NA
# 3  2  2  1
# 4 NA NA  1
```

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich -- Thought you might like that. Yours is faster, though, and scales much better, so this is really just a curiosity. (I `system.time()`'d both with `x <- rep("1 2", 1e5)` etc.)