# Splitting a vector of strings to a dataframe with columns containing the respective characters

Tags: r, string, split

As a variant of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079431/how-to-convert-a-vector-of-strings-to-a-dataframe-or-matrix)

I have a vector with strings, each string has 2 to 4 characters.

```
Strng <- c("XDX",  "GUV",  "FQ",   "ACUE", "HIT",  "AYX",  "NFD",  "AHBW", "GKQ",  "PYF")
```

I want to split it to data frame with 4 columns, where each column contains one of the characters or 0 (for the case where the length of the string is less tan 4). The zeros can be in front of - doesn't matter.

So (probably) after applying this:

```
ss<-strsplit(Strng,"")
z<-lapply(ss,as.character)
```

I would like to have a dataframe like this:

```
>df  
"X" "D" "X" "0"  
"G" "U" "V" "0"  
"F" "Q" "0" "0"   
"A" "C" "U" "E" 
"H" "I" "T" "0"  
"A" "Y" "X" "0"  
"N" "F" "D" "0"  
"A" "H" "B" "W" 
"G" "K" "Q" "0"  
"P" "Y" "F" "0"
```

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Kalin

Comment: Here's a base R alternative `t(sapply(ss, 'length<-', max(lengths(ss))))` (you can replace NAs with 0 afterwards if needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tstrsplit(Strng, "", fill = "0"))[]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4
#  1:  X  D  X  0
#  2:  G  U  V  0
#  3:  F  Q  0  0
#  4:  A  C  U  E
#  5:  H  I  T  0
#  6:  A  Y  X  0
#  7:  N  F  D  0
#  8:  A  H  B  W
#  9:  G  K  Q  0
# 10:  P  Y  F  0
```

---

You could also use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, but it fills with `NA` and uses a little bit strange syntax:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(data.table(Strng), "Strng", "", stripWhite = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi` after we split the "Strng" to a `list`.

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(strsplit(Strng, ''), fill=0, byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "X"  "D"  "X"  "0" 
# [2,] "G"  "U"  "V"  "0" 
# [3,] "F"  "Q"  "0"  "0" 
# [4,] "A"  "C"  "U"  "E" 
# [5,] "H"  "I"  "T"  "0" 
# [6,] "A"  "Y"  "X"  "0" 
# [7,] "N"  "F"  "D"  "0" 
# [8,] "A"  "H"  "B"  "W" 
# [9,] "G"  "K"  "Q"  "0" 
#[10,] "P"  "Y"  "F"  "0"
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be (variant of the one described in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079431/how-to-convert-a-vector-of-strings-to-a-dataframe-or-matrix))

```
read.fwf(file= textConnection(Strng), 
             widths = rep(1,max(nchar(Strng))))
```

Comment: @RHertel  I was correcting that with `byrow=TRUE`.  Thanks.